# void* alternative in C#

Tags: c#, function, arguments, void-pointers

I am making a class that calls a callback function and I want it to pass some data in some cases but that data may vary. In C++ I would use void* but in C# it's unsafe and it means it might get GCed. Is there any way of passing unknown type of data in C#?

Comment: Great power implies great responsibility. I mean even though C++ allows to do such tricks - don't forget about design.

Comment: The real question is why are you making a function that is going to have to "guess" what type of data it is processing?

Comment: In my mind, a callback (delegate) with undefined argument type, is result of the weak application design. Can you provide additional information?

Comment: Weak design is possible because I'm still relatively new to C# and right now I am making a new class for nearly every specific mouse click. All the elements are created dynamically and added to StackPanels or Grids mostly but they have functions, for example for hiding them. In order to do that, I have to save a reference to it somewhere, so I make a class for that kind of mouse clicks only. And it goes on and on... Right now I'm trying to make some universal click handler that would pass such data to callback function which would reduce amount of code dramatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got two options:

[Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192.aspx#Y200) (which allow you to specify the type when you call the method... and the object will be properly typed within the method.)

```
// Definition:
public void MyMethod<T>(T myParameter)
{
    /* My Code */
}

// Call:
MyMethod<int>(999);

// Call:
MyMethod<bool>(false);
```

Or [System.Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) (which means you'll have to ascertain the object's actual type inside your method and cast appropriately)

```
// Definition:
public void MyMethod(Object myParameter)
{
    /* My Code */
}

// Call:
MyMethod(999);

// Call:
MyMethod(false);
```

Comment: Just be prepared to type convert whatever you want.

Comment: @Tejs: I'd even say "cast" not "convert"

Comment: Whenever you get `System.Object` involved, that's a sign that there's a strong chance you're doing it wrong.

Comment: If you're writing all your own code, to be used by your own code (which most people are doing) then yes.

Comment: @antisanity - glad you agree!

Comment: Heh thanks! Yes, both work fine. It's probably the 'best-practice' paranoia that I still feel when I look at C#. Using generics in this manner does come out more verbose, but generally safer. I would also argue that in more general terms it would make sense to pass a callback object that encapsulates the data, although the question isn't entirely clear.

Answer (score 8):

You should use Generics for this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx

Comment: Hmm... Generics... Forgot about them. Yeah, that might be a solution for me ;)

Comment: Heh, looks like @antisanity incorporated my answer into his.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use the `object` type because all other objects inherit from this object. Doing so you allow yourself to pass in any object type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You'd pass it around at an **object**. Unlike C++ you'll be able to do a type safe cast in C#, whereas you can't in C++.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Object.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in .net 4 you can also use the `dynamic` type.